# How disconnect bathroom exhaust fan from conduit?

Tags: electrical, conduit, exhaust-fan

I'm trying to remove an exhaust fan from the 1950s which is connected to some conduit. I'm used to having a box that things are connected to so I have never removed a direct conduit connection. I have tried to turn the nut on the top with a wrench but to no avail. Not sure if there is a different way or I just need more strength.
Photo from inside the fan housing [image: inside fan housing]

And photo from above where the conduit is connected
[image]

Comment: The ring/nut on the inside of the box should turn to loosen.  Possible you might have to hold the big nut on the outside also.  I imagine working on both at the same time will be difficult, so a pair of locking pliers on the top nut will be useful.

Answer (score 3):

The nut on the top will loosen the conduit from the connector. The nut inside the box will loosen the connector from the box. If you can't get a wrench on that nut, take a slotted screwdriver and put it on one of the lips on the nut and hit it with a hammer a few times in a counterclockwise direction. That should loosen it. Careful you don't damage the wires.

Comment: Can't get a wrench on the one inside very well because it's set back in there and there isn't really anywhere for a screwdriver to grab onto. Been trying to hammer a screwdriver at it anyway but it isn't budging

Comment: @user3242036 Then you'll need to attack it from the top and loosen that nut. You might need a bigger wrench.

Comment: @user3242036 can you fit a needlenose vise grip inside the fan box?